# What is the equivalent for LinkedList<T> in Golang

Tags: list, struct, go, linked-list

In my use case, I would like to know how the following Java code would be implemented in Go

```
class TreeNode {
    public int data;
    public TreeNode left;
    public TreeNode right;
    public TreeNode(){}
}

LinkedList<TreeNode> treeList = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
```

I am able to import the container/list package and add an interface. But it is not allowing any generic object. Do I have to implement my own version of list with TreeNode struct?

I just need to know how `LinkedList<T>` would work in Go.

**EDIT 1:**  To make it clear, I am adding the complete code here. I am trying to find the linked list of all nodes at each depth in a binary tree. I used two packages list and binary tree. You can find the source code for binarytree [here](https://github.com/dineshappavoo/ctci-go/blob/master/src/go/chapter04-treesandgraphs/binarytree/binarytree.go) and list [here](https://github.com/dineshappavoo/ctci-go/blob/master/src/go/chapter02-linkedlists/list/list.go). list is same as container/list but I added few extra functions

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "go/chapter02-linkedlists/list"
    "go/chapter04-treesandgraphs/binarytree"
)
func main() {

    inArr := []int{4, 5, 7, 8, 9}
    t1 := binarytree.NewMinimalHeightBST(inArr, 0, len(inArr)-1)
    binarytree.InOrderTraverse(t1)
    var nodeList []*list.List

    nodeList = getLevelbasedList(t1, 0)

    fmt.Println()
    for _, value := range nodeList {
        fmt.Print("[ ")
        for x := value.Front(); x != nil; x = x.Next() {
            fmt.Print(x.Value.(int), " ")
        }
        fmt.Println("]")
    }
}

func getLevelbasedList(root *binarytree.Tree, level int) []*list.List {
    if root == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var nodeList []*list.List
    parents := list.New()
    current := list.New()

    current.PushFront(root)

    for current.Len() > 0 {
        nodeList = append(nodeList, current)
        parents = current
        current = list.New()

        for x := current.Front(); x != nil; x = x.Next() {
            node := x.Value.(*binarytree.Tree)
            if node.Left != nil {
                current = current.PushFront(node.Left)
            }
            if node.Right != nil {
                current = current.PushFront(node.Right)
            }
        }
        return nodeList
    }
}
```

And the error is,

```
./question4_4b.go:56: cannot use current.PushFront((interface {})(node.Left)) (type *list.Element) as type *list.List in assignment
./question4_4b.go:59: cannot use current.PushFront((interface {})(node.Right)) (type *list.Element) as type *list.List in assignment
```

**EDIT 2:** Based on JamesHenstridge's comment I edited from

```
current = current.PushFront(node.Left)
```

to

```
current.PushFront(node.Left)
```

And the issue resolved. But now I am getting interface conversion error,

```
[ panic: interface conversion: interface is *binarytree.Tree, not int

goroutine 1 [running]:
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not allowing any generic object"? Why exactly could you not use `container/list`?

Comment: @Ainar-G - I added complete code. I am getting error while accessing Tree struct

Comment: `PushFront` returns an element, not a list.

Comment: @DineshAppavoo: You're assigning the result of `current.PushFront(...)` to `current`, however `current` is a `*List` and `PushFront` returns a `*Element`.  You don't need the assignment.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge - Thank you. It helped. But still I am getting interface coversion issue.

Comment: Fixed the issue. Error was in the print statement. I didnt parse as a Tree object. Thank You

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go doesn't support generic types (see FAQ question [Why does Go not have generic types?](http://golang.org/doc/faq#generics)).

You have to use [Type assertions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to obtain the typed value you want.

E.g. create your `TreeNode` type:

```
type TreeNode struct {
    Data  int
    Left  *TreeNode
    Right *TreeNode
}
```

And to iterate over a list containing `TreeNode` values:

```
l := list.New()
// Populate list

for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
    if tn, ok := e.Value.(TreeNode); ok {
        // do something with tn which is of type TreeNode
        fmt.Println(tn)
    } else {
        // e.Value is not of type TreeNode
    }
}
```

If you assemble the list and you can be sure it only contains values of type `TreeNode`, you can omit the error check in the type assertion and it becomes like this:

```
for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
    // if e.Value would not be of type TreeNode, run-time panic would occur
    tn := e.Value.(TreeNode) // tn is of type TreeNode
    fmt.Println(tn)

}
```

**Edit:**

The error you're getting:

```
cannot use current.PushFront((interface {})(node.Left)) (type *list.Element)
    as type *list.List in assignment
```

At line:

```
current = current.PushFront(node.Left)
```

The `current` variable is of type `list.List`, and the method `current.PushFront()` returns a value of type `*list.Element`. These are 2 different types, you can't assign a `*Element` to a variable that has a type of `List`.

**Edit 2:**

Your 2nd error:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface is *binarytree.Tree, not int
```

Is caused by the line:

```
fmt.Print(x.Value.(int), " ")
```

You try to assert that the value `x.Value` is of type `int` but it isn't! `x.Value` is of type `*binarytree.Tree` so the assertion will obviously fail.

Comment: It helps. But still getting error. I added the code above. I am getting error while accessing Tree struct

Comment: @DineshAppavoo And what is the error you're getting?

Comment: @DineshAppavoo Edited my answer to explain why you get that error.

Comment: I edited the code based on your suggestion . But I am getting interface conversion error

Comment: Fixed the issue. Error was in the print statement of return object. I didn't parse as a Tree object. Thank You

Comment: Now Go supports generics.

Comment: Go now supports Generics, see an example in my other answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239452/1618202