# Implement generic linked list in golang which disallows different types in the same linkedlist

Tags: go, data-structures, linked-list

I want to make a linked list which can hold the **values of any type** but the linked list must hold values of any **one type only**.

In general when I am using interfaces for achieving this - any type which implements the interface for the node can be added to the linked list.

I have written an implementation for this where whenever a new key is added to the linked list, the type of the key is checked against the type of the key at the head. I want to understand if this is the correct way of implementing it or is there a better way of doing it.

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)

type MyNode struct {
    value int
}

func (node *MyNode) PrintValue() {
    fmt.Printf(" %d ", node.value)
}

type llNode struct {
    key        llNodeInterface
    next       *llNode
    llNodeType reflect.Type
}

type llNodeInterface interface {
    PrintValue()
}

type ComplexNode struct {
    realValue  int
    imageValue int
}

func (node *ComplexNode) PrintValue() {
    fmt.Printf(" %d + i%d", node.realValue, node.imageValue)
}

// Student type.
type Student struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

// Student implements the PrintValue function - thus llNodeInterface is implemented.
func (node *Student) PrintValue() {
    fmt.Printf("Name: %s | Age : %d ", node.name, node.age)
}

// Function which will check the of the new node before adding to the linked
// list. It checks the type of the new key against the type of the key in the
// head. If both are equal then it proceed else return error.
func (head *llNode) AddBeforeHeadTypeCheck(passedKey llNodeInterface) error {

    if head.key == nil {
        head.key = passedKey
        head.llNodeType = reflect.TypeOf(head.key)
    } else {
        typeOfPassedKey := reflect.TypeOf(passedKey)

        if typeOfPassedKey != head.llNodeType {
            fmt.Printf("\nUnsupported type for the type %T", passedKey)
            return errors.New("Type mistmatch")
        }

        temp := llNode{key: head.key, next: head.next}
        head.key = passedKey
        head.next = &temp
    }
    return nil
}

// Function which will not check the types and will simply add the new node to
// the linked list. Thus linked list will be able to have nodes of multiple
// types.
func (head *llNode) AddBeforeHead(passedKey llNodeInterface) {

    if head.key == nil {
        head.key = passedKey
        head.llNodeType = reflect.TypeOf(head.key)
    } else {
        temp := llNode{key: head.key, next: head.next}
        head.key = passedKey
        head.next = &temp
    }
}

func (head *llNode) Init() {
    head.key = nil
    head.next = nil
    head.llNodeType = nil

}

// Print the linked list.
func (head *llNode) DisplayLL() {

    temp := head
    fmt.Printf("\n%s", strings.Repeat("#", 80))
    fmt.Printf("\nPrinting the linked list\n")

    for {
        if temp.key == nil {
            fmt.Println("Linked list is empty")
            break
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("\n %T %v ", temp.key, temp.key)
            key := temp.key
            key.PrintValue()
            if temp.next == nil {
                break
            } else {
                temp = temp.next
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n%s", strings.Repeat("#", 80))
    fmt.Printf("\n\n")
}

func testWithMixedType() {
    head := llNode{}
    head.Init()

    for i := 1; i < 10; i++ {
        temp := &ComplexNode{i, i * 10}
        head.AddBeforeHeadTypeCheck(temp)
    }

    temps := &Student{"rishi", 20}
    head.AddBeforeHeadTypeCheck(temps) // Will give error.
    head.DisplayLL()
}

func testWithComplexNumber() {

    head := llNode{}
    head.Init()

    for i := 1; i < 10; i++ {
        temp := &ComplexNode{i, i * 10}
        head.AddBeforeHeadTypeCheck(temp)
    }

}

func main() {
    testWithComplexNumber()
    testWithMixedType()

}
```

The code is working fine - but I want to understand if there is a better or different way of doing this.

Also - what is the performance impact of the current checking of types using the reflect package. Is there a different way of achieving the same thing.

Unsupported type for the type *main.Student

```
Unsupported type for the type *main.Student
################################################################################
Printing the linked list

 *main.ComplexNode &{9 90}  9 + i90
 *main.ComplexNode &{8 80}  8 + i80
 *main.ComplexNode &{7 70}  7 + i70
 *main.ComplexNode &{6 60}  6 + i60
 *main.ComplexNode &{5 50}  5 + i50
 *main.ComplexNode &{4 40}  4 + i40
 *main.ComplexNode &{3 30}  3 + i30
 *main.ComplexNode &{2 20}  2 + i20
 *main.ComplexNode &{1 10}  1 + i10
################################################################################
```

Comment: "if there is a better or different way of doing this". Yes: Stop writing generic code. Either use an appropriate interface or use a non-generic container. "what is the performance impact of the current checking of types" Measure! Nobody can tell you if this is fast enough for your workload on your infrastructure.

Comment: This isn't typical Go code. It's not clear why the list implementation would care if the user mixes types or not. If you explain *why* you want to create such a list, we can maybe suggest alternatives, although it usually boils down to writing (or generating) multiple implementations.

Comment: @Peter - in cpp when we create a container - lets say a vector, we need to mention the type of objects that will be in the container. It can be seen as a feature or a limitation, but in my case - I do not want the users to be able to keep different types of objects in the container. Consider a case where I want the keys in the linked list to be stored in a sorted order. How will I compare the objects of different types in the linked list.

Comment: @Volker - performance impact - I think I worded it incorrectly - The question is "What is the impact of using the reflect package in the code ? Can this be removed by using another method. I am editing the question to mention this.

Comment: Using reflection happens at runtime and is _always_ slower than using direct code. The only way to get rid of the reflection overhead is to write non-generic code which you should do.

Comment: The usual way to solve this is with code generation in Go. At least until it gets generics... Take a look at p. 352 of `Learning Functional Programming in Go'. Though, if you really really need to use FP data structures use something else than go (like F# or Scala), or simply use a different data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news, starting from Go 1.18, [Generics are now supported in Go](https://go.dev/blog/intro-generics).

Following the example from the question, here is a simplified LinkedList using Generics. You can tinker with it at [the playground here](https://go.dev/play/p/vmYqMJnTW_F).

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyNode[T any] struct {
    next  *MyNode[T]
    value T
}

type MyLinkedList[T any] struct {
    head *MyNode[T]
    tail *MyNode[T]
}

func (list *MyLinkedList[T]) Add(t T) *MyLinkedList[T] {
    // create node
    node := &MyNode[T]{nil, t}
    // if first node in list
    if list.head == nil {
        list.head = node
        list.tail = node
    } else {
        list.tail.next = node
        list.tail = list.tail.next
    }

    return list
}

func (list *MyLinkedList[T]) AddBeforeHead(t T) *MyLinkedList[T] {
    node := &MyNode[T]{nil, t}
    if list.head != nil {
        node.next = list.head
        list.head = node
    } else {
        // make head
        list.head = node
        list.tail = node
    }

    return list
}

// display the list
func DisplayList[T any](list *MyLinkedList[T]) string {
    var out string = ""
    iter := list.head
    for iter != nil {
        out += fmt.Sprintf("%v -> ", iter.value)
        iter = iter.next
    }
    return out
}

func (list *MyLinkedList[T]) Display() string {
    return DisplayList(list)
}

// for printing node value
// you could also implement Stringer
// but this is besides the point, you can ignore
func (node *MyNode[T]) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("<MyNode: %v>", node.value)
}

// helper func: create list from array
func CreateLinkedList[T any](arr []T) *MyLinkedList[T] {
    list := &MyLinkedList[T]{}

    for _, v := range arr {
        list.Add(v)
    }

    return list
}

func main() {
    // create a list from array of integers
    intArr := []int{10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60}
    list1 := CreateLinkedList(intArr)
    // create a list from array of strings
    strArr := []string{"foo", "bar", "baz", "faz"}
    list2 := CreateLinkedList(strArr)

    // test inserting at the beginning
    list2.AddBeforeHead("hello")

    fmt.Println(list1.Display())
    fmt.Println(list2.Display())
}
```

Some official references covering basics of Generics can be found here:

- https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics
- https://go.dev/blog/intro-generics
- https://go.dev/tour/generics/1

Answer (score 1):

You can do it either by using interfaces and runtime checks (as you've discovered), or by using [code generation](https://blog.golang.org/generate). These are the current options you have in Go for generic programming. The Go team is working to [add generics to the language](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/go2draft-generics-overview.md) - it's a work in progress, and everyone is free to participate in the discussion. Once generics exist, they will provide the solution you seek here.

As for interfaces vs. code generation, there are the performance implications you've mentioned. Code generation will generate tighter code that doesn't need to do runtime checks for most operations; on the other hand, it adds a bit of complexity to the build process of your project. These are the usual tradeoffs of having something resolved at run-time vs. precomputing things at compile-time.